# How to show value of django field conditionaly from child or parent model

Tags: python, django, model

I have the following parent model

```
class Parent(Model):

    value1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    .......
```

and the child model

```
class Child(Model)

     value1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
     value2 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
     ...........
```

how can I return the value of field conditionally?

how can I show in templates (tables/lists or details) from parent field if the field with the same name from the child has the value None.

And if value of field in child is not None show the value from child.

Can I filter data (Childrens) in the same way?

---

Should I use some abstract or proxy models? How?

Comment: If two models are related, use [relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/).

Comment: Make sure you have a foreign key on the Child Model.

Answer (score 0):

I added some answers because I think that I didn't describe my question accurate.

1. I need to create some of abstraction level where the top level model will have some of the 'main' fields
2. All the derivatives/childs of top level have the same fields as this top level and some more specyfic fields.
3. If one of the child fields (this from top level) is not chaged than the top level field is presented,
4. If change occurred then the value from child is presented.
5. if change occurred on the top-level model all childs which have not been changed will present the data from top model.

---

My idea is to use ManyToOne relationship and have to models Parent and Child, where child will have the same fields as parent (data dupplication) and some more extra fields.

When a child is created I plan to copy data from parents for duplicated fields.

For each duplicated field on child I plan to add boolean field for checking if field has changed and change it accordingly to true on save of child changed field.

When Parent saves occurs I plan to add an extra method to overwrite the child field and copy parent data if child boolean (field_changed) is set as false, else do not overwrite.

Is there a better method for this?